# Sylow p-subgroups and set X not divisible by p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $P\subseteq Z(G)$.  Show that the set $X$ of elements of $G$ with order not divisible by $p$ is a  subgroup of $G$ and that $G=P\times X$.

I can see that $X\neq \phi$, and $X$ is closed under inversions. How do I show $X$ is closed under multiplication?

To show that $G=P\times X$, my first thought is to take the quotient $G/X=(P\times X)/X=P$.

Comment: Do you know about the [transfer homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_%28group_theory%29)?

Comment: It could also be done using the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Comment: As I recall, this is an exercise in some introductory textbook (possibly Gallian?), and it is meant to be done with just Sylow's theorems and not much else. Could you elaborate where it is from?

Comment: Yes I have the feeling that there should be a proof that does not rely on Schur-Zassenhaus or transfer, but have not come up with one. Incidentally, once you know that $X$ is a subgroup, it is not hard to prove that $G = P \times X$: clearly $P \cap X = \{ 1 \}$, so you just need to check that $G=PX$.

Comment: I am aware of Schur-Zassenhaus but not transfer homomorphism.
How do we know that $G=P\times X=PX$ when $P\cap X=\{1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming that $G$  is finite, furthermore, $\left|G\right|=p^{n}m$  with $p$ prime and $m\in \mathbb{N_{>0}}$  where $\left(m,p\right)=1$, then $\left|P\right|=p^n$. Moreover $P\trianglelefteq G$ because $P\subseteq Z\left(G\right)$.

First we show that $X$ is subgroup of $G$, indeed, $X\neq\phi$  because we can consider the prime factorization of $m$  and choose one of these factors and apply the Cauchy Theorem. Clearly $X$ is closed under inversions. Let us prove that $X$ is closed under multiplication, indeed, let  $a,b\in X$, then $\left\langle ab\right\rangle \leq\left\langle \left\langle a\right\rangle \left\langle b\right\rangle \right\rangle $  and  we know that $\left|\left\langle \left\langle a\right\rangle \left\langle b\right\rangle \right\rangle \right|=\frac{\left|a\right|\left|b\right|}{\left|\left\langle a\right\rangle \cap\left\langle b\right\rangle \right|}$ where  $\left|a\right|$, $\left|b\right|$  and $\left|\left\langle a\right\rangle \cap\left\langle b\right\rangle \right|$ do not divisible by $p$, then $\left|\left\langle \left\langle a\right\rangle \left\langle b\right\rangle \right\rangle \right|$ is not divisible by $p$, in particular, $\left|ab\right|$ is not divisible by $p$.

Note that $p\nmid \left|X\right|$ because if it were not so then there would be a subgroup of $X$ of order $p$. Therefore  $\left|X\right|$ divide to $m$, furthermore,  $\left|X\right|=m$, indeed,  we  consider the prime factorization of $m=q_{1}^{k_{1}}q_{2}^{k_{2}}\dots q_{s}^{k_{s}}$  where $q_{s}$ are prime numbers different of $p$, as $\left|X\right|$ divide to $m$   suppose that $\left|X\right|\neq m$, then, without loss of generality, we consider  $\left|X\right|=q_{1}^{k_{1}}q_{2}^{k_{2}}\dots q_{t}^{k_{t}}$  with $t<s$, but by First Sylow Theorem there is a Sylow $q_{j}$-supgroup $H_{j}$ of $G$ of order $q_{j}^{k_{j}}$ for each $t<j\leq s$, note that the order of each element in $H_{j}$ is not divisible by $p$, then $H_{j}\leq X$, therefore  $q_{j}^{k_{j}}$ divide to $\left|X\right|$ which contradicts our supposition.

Finally, as  $P\trianglelefteq G$ then $PX\leq G$, mareover,  clearly $P\cap X=\left\{ e\right\}$. Therefore $\left|PX\right|=\left|P\right|\left|X\right|=p^nm=\left|G\right|$, hence, $G=PX$.

Comment: It is not always true, that $|\langle\langle a\rangle,\langle b\rangle\rangle|=\frac{|a||b|}{|\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle|}$. For example, let $G=S_n$, $n>3$, $a=(1,2)$, $b=(1,2,\ldots,n)$. Then $\langle a,b\rangle=G$, thus $G=\langle\langle a\rangle,\langle b\rangle\rangle$, but $|G|=n!$, and $\frac{|a||b|}{|\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle|}\shortmid 2n<n!$ for $n>3$.